# How can i read an unnamed JSON array in android?

Tags: android, json

I am trying to read from a JSON array like the one below. How can I do this?

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
                //activities = jsonObject.getJSONArray(0);//JSON_ARRAY);
                activities = jsonObject.getJSONArray("{}");

                //for (int i = 0, count = activities.length(); i < count; i++) {
                for (int i = 0, count = jsonObject.length(); i < count; i++) {
                    // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
                    JSONObject jsonObj = jsonObject;//.getJSONObject([i].name);

                    String name = jsonObj.getString("name");
                    double longi = jsonObj.getDouble("longitude");
                    double lati = jsonObj.getDouble("latitude");
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

{  
   "57061f1c7d38736c738b4567":{  
      "business":{  
         "level":"3",
         "logo":"roovertscheleij_logo_web.png",
         "name":"Eet- en Drinkerij De Roovertsche Leij",
         "link":"http:\/\/roovertscheleij.nl\/",
         "latitude":"51.4866988",
         "longitude":"5.0560597",
         "id":"5654347e7d3873d73f8b4577",
         "slug":"eet-en-drinkerij-de-roovertsche-leij",
         "hide_from_view":false,
         "created_at":"2015-11-24T10:57:18+0100",
         "updated_at":"2016-04-05T16:00:13+0200",
         "phone":"013 577 43 00",
         "email":"info@roovertscheleij.nl",
         "images":[  
            "1.png",
            "2.jpg",
            "IMG_1838 (Medium)-660x440.JPG"
         ],
         "accessibility":[  

         ],
         "address":"Gorps Baantje 1",
         "coordinates":{  
            "longitude":5.0560597,
            "latitude":51.4866988
         },
         "facebook":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/roovertscheleij"
      },
      "category":{  
         "colors_map":{  
            "bewoner":{  
               "marker":"waypoint-marker",
               "color":"#554455"
            },
            "bezoeker":{  
               "marker":"waypoint-marker",
               "color":"#445544"
            },
            "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
               "color":"#F09DBD",
               "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
            },
            "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
               "color":"#84B550",
               "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
            },
            "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
               "color":"#FF8336",
               "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
            },
            "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
               "color":"#E13F42",
               "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
            },
            "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
               "color":"#1E97C7",
               "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
            },
            "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
               "color":"#55C292",
               "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
            },
            "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
               "color":"#9F7ECF",
               "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
            },
            "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
               "color":"#FFC64E",
               "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
            },
            "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
               "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
               "color":"#65DAE5",
               "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
            }
         },
         "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|Dagje uit-54aae46c7d387323748b45b5|Actief en Sportief-54aae4ab7d387324748b459c|Wandelen-54aae8a27d38734c098b465d|",
         "parent":{  
            "colors_map":{  
               "bewoner":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                  "color":"#554455"
               },
               "bezoeker":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                  "color":"#445544"
               },
               "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
                  "color":"#F09DBD",
                  "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
               },
               "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
                  "color":"#84B550",
                  "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
               },
               "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
                  "color":"#FF8336",
                  "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
               },
               "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
                  "color":"#E13F42",
                  "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
               },
               "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
                  "color":"#1E97C7",
                  "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
               },
               "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
                  "color":"#55C292",
                  "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
               },
               "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
                  "color":"#9F7ECF",
                  "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
               },
               "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
                  "color":"#FFC64E",
                  "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
               },
               "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
                  "color":"#65DAE5",
                  "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
               }
            },
            "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|Dagje uit-54aae46c7d387323748b45b5|Actief en Sportief-54aae4ab7d387324748b459c|",
            "parent":{  
               "colors_map":{  
                  "bewoner":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                     "color":"#554455"
                  },
                  "bezoeker":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                     "color":"#445544"
                  },
                  "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
                     "color":"#F09DBD",
                     "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
                  },
                  "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
                     "color":"#84B550",
                     "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
                  },
                  "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
                     "color":"#FF8336",
                     "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
                  },
                  "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
                     "color":"#E13F42",
                     "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
                  },
                  "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
                     "color":"#1E97C7",
                     "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
                     "color":"#55C292",
                     "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
                     "color":"#9F7ECF",
                     "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
                     "color":"#FFC64E",
                     "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
                     "color":"#65DAE5",
                     "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
                  }
               },
               "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|Dagje uit-54aae46c7d387323748b45b5|",
               "parent":{  
                  "colors_map":{  
                     "bewoner":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                        "color":"#554455"
                     },
                     "bezoeker":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                        "color":"#445544"
                     },
                     "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
                        "color":"#F09DBD",
                        "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
                     },
                     "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
                        "color":"#84B550",
                        "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
                     },
                     "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
                        "color":"#FF8336",
                        "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
                     },
                     "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
                        "color":"#E13F42",
                        "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
                     },
                     "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
                        "color":"#1E97C7",
                        "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
                     },
                     "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
                        "color":"#55C292",
                        "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
                     },
                     "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
                        "color":"#9F7ECF",
                        "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
                     },
                     "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
                        "color":"#FFC64E",
                        "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
                     },
                     "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
                        "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
                        "color":"#65DAE5",
                        "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
                     }
                  },
                  "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|",
                  "level":1,
                  "color":"aaaaaa",
                  "custom_color":"transparent",
                  "label":"visitor",
                  "id":"54aae1697d387323748b4569",
                  "slug":"bezoeker",
                  "title":"Bezoeker"
               },
               "level":2,
               "color":"aaaaaa",
               "custom_color":"transparent",
               "label":"",
               "id":"54aae46c7d387323748b45b5",
               "slug":"dagje-uit",
               "updated_at":"2016-02-15T08:43:25+0100",
               "title":"Dagje uit",
               "images":[  
                  "test.jpg"
               ]
            },
            "level":3,
            "color":"55C292",
            "custom_color":"transparent",
            "label":"",
            "id":"54aae4ab7d387324748b459c",
            "slug":"actief-en-sportief",
            "title":"Actief en Sportief"
         },
         "level":4,
         "color":"55C292",
         "custom_color":"transparent",
         "label":"",
         "id":"54aae8a27d38734c098b465d",
         "slug":"wandelen",
         "title":"Wandelen"
      },
      "number_of_people":"niet van toepassing",
      "target_group":[  
         "alle-leeftijden"
      ],
      "part_of_the_day":"niet van toepassing",
      "price_type":"inapplicable",
      "price_p_p":false,
      "address":"Gorps Baantje 1",
      "postal_code":"5051 PX",
      "city":"Goirle",
      "link":"http:\/\/roovertscheleij.nl\/activiteiten-roovertsche-lei\/",
      "id":"57061f1c7d38736c738b4567",
      "slug":"wandelen-onder-begeleiding",
      "hide_from_view":false,
      "created_at":"2016-04-07T00:00:00+0200",
      "updated_at":"2016-04-07T10:56:28+0200",
      "expires_at":"2020-04-07T00:00:00+0200",
      "title":"Wandelen onder begeleiding",
      "description":"\u003Cp\u003EWandelen onder begeleiding is wandelen met een IVN gids. Deze gids is speciaal opgeleid om jou de mooiste plekken te laten zien en te vertellen over het gebied en de prachtige natuur. Zo wandel je niet alleen door de prachtige natuur, maar steek je er ook nog wat van op!\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/p\u003E",
      "coordinates":{  
         "longitude":5.0560597,
         "latitude":51.4866988,
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[  
            5.0560597,
            51.4866988
         ]
      },
      "images":[  
         "570620ba14c28.jpg"
      ],
      "location":{  
         "path":"Nederland-55389c647d387315588b4567|Noord-Brabant-55389c717d387315588b4568|",
         "level":2,
         "id":"55389c717d387315588b4568",
         "slug":"noord-brabant",
         "updated_at":"2016-02-24T17:02:01+0100",
         "title":"Noord-Brabant",
         "coordinates":{  
            "longitude":5.2321687,
            "latitude":51.4826537
         }
      }
   },
   "57061a747d38736a6d8b456a":{  
      "business":{  
         "name":"Bed \u0026 Breakfast-mieke",
         "link":"http:\/\/www.bedandbreakfast-mieke.eu",
         "id":"570617b07d38736a6d8b4569",
         "slug":"bed-breakfast-mieke",
         "hide_from_view":false,
         "created_at":"2016-04-07T10:17:52+0200",
         "updated_at":"2016-04-07T10:33:41+0200",
         "phone":"0161 223 115",
         "email":"bedandbreakfast.mieke@gmail.com",
         "images":[  
            "57061831e0fd7.png",
            "570619bfde844.png",
            "570619c5565db.png"
         ],
         "accessibility":[  

         ],
         "address":"Memlingstraat 19",
         "coordinates":{  
            "longitude":4.9134973,
            "latitude":51.5874298,
            "type":"Point",
            "coordinates":[  
               4.9134973,
               51.5874298
            ]
         },
         "location":{  
            "path":"Nederland-55389c647d387315588b4567|Noord-Brabant-55389c717d387315588b4568|",
            "level":2,
            "id":"55389c717d387315588b4568",
            "slug":"noord-brabant",
            "updated_at":"2016-02-24T17:02:01+0100",
            "title":"Noord-Brabant",
            "coordinates":{  
               "longitude":5.2321687,
               "latitude":51.4826537
            }
         }
      },
      "category":{  
         "colors_map":{  
            "bewoner":{  
               "marker":"waypoint-marker",
               "color":"#554455"
            },
            "bezoeker":{  
               "marker":"waypoint-marker",
               "color":"#445544"
            },
            "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
               "color":"#F09DBD",
               "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
            },
            "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
               "color":"#84B550",
               "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
            },
            "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
               "color":"#FF8336",
               "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
            },
            "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
               "color":"#E13F42",
               "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
            },
            "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
               "color":"#1E97C7",
               "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
            },
            "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
               "color":"#55C292",
               "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
            },
            "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
               "color":"#9F7ECF",
               "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
            },
            "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
               "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
               "color":"#FFC64E",
               "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
            },
            "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
               "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
               "color":"#65DAE5",
               "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
            }
         },
         "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|Overnachting-54aae46c7d387323748b45b7|Bed en Breakfast-54aae50d7d387323748b45d5|",
         "parent":{  
            "colors_map":{  
               "bewoner":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                  "color":"#554455"
               },
               "bezoeker":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                  "color":"#445544"
               },
               "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
                  "color":"#F09DBD",
                  "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
               },
               "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
                  "color":"#84B550",
                  "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
               },
               "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
                  "color":"#FF8336",
                  "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
               },
               "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
                  "color":"#E13F42",
                  "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
               },
               "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
                  "color":"#1E97C7",
                  "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
               },
               "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
                  "color":"#55C292",
                  "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
               },
               "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
                  "color":"#9F7ECF",
                  "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
               },
               "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
                  "color":"#FFC64E",
                  "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
               },
               "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
                  "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
                  "color":"#65DAE5",
                  "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
               }
            },
            "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|Overnachting-54aae46c7d387323748b45b7|",
            "parent":{  
               "colors_map":{  
                  "bewoner":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                     "color":"#554455"
                  },
                  "bezoeker":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint-marker",
                     "color":"#445544"
                  },
                  "bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging",
                     "color":"#F09DBD",
                     "img":"bewoner_gezondheid-en-verzorging"
                  },
                  "bewoner_huis-en-tuin":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_huis-en-tuin",
                     "color":"#84B550",
                     "img":"bewoner_huis-en-tuin"
                  },
                  "bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen",
                     "color":"#FF8336",
                     "img":"bewoner_vrije-tijd-en-winkelen"
                  },
                  "bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening",
                     "color":"#E13F42",
                     "img":"bewoner_zakelijk-en-dienstverlening"
                  },
                  "bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit",
                     "color":"#1E97C7",
                     "img":"bewoner_vervoer-en-mobiliteit"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_dagje-uit":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_dagje-uit",
                     "color":"#55C292",
                     "img":"bezoeker_dagje-uit"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_kinderen":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_kinderen",
                     "color":"#9F7ECF",
                     "img":"bezoeker_kinderen"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_uit-eten":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint_bezoeker_eten-en-drinken",
                     "color":"#FFC64E",
                     "img":" bezoeker_uit-eten"
                  },
                  "bezoeker_overnachting":{  
                     "marker":"waypoint-bezoeker_overnachting",
                     "color":"#65DAE5",
                     "img":"bezoeker_overnachting"
                  }
               },
               "path":"Bezoeker-54aae1697d387323748b4569|",
               "level":1,
               "color":"aaaaaa",
               "custom_color":"transparent",
               "label":"visitor",
               "id":"54aae1697d387323748b4569",
               "slug":"bezoeker",
               "title":"Bezoeker"
            },
            "level":2,
            "color":"aaaaaa",
            "custom_color":"transparent",
            "label":"",
            "id":"54aae46c7d387323748b45b7",
            "slug":"overnachting",
            "title":"Overnachting",
            "images":[  
               "test.jpg"
            ]
         },
         "level":3,
         "color":"65DAE5",
         "custom_color":"transparent",
         "label":"",
         "id":"54aae50d7d387323748b45d5",
         "slug":"bed-en-breakfast",
         "title":"Bed en Breakfast"
      },
      "number_of_people":"niet van toepassing",
      "target_group":[  
         "alle-leeftijden"
      ],
      "part_of_the_day":"evening",
      "price_type":"fixed",
      "price":35,
      "price_p_p":false,
      "address":"Memlingstraat 19",
      "postal_code":"5121 WG",
      "city":"Rijen",
      "id":"57061a747d38736a6d8b456a",
      "slug":"overnachten-bij-bed-breakfast-mieke",
      "hide_from_view":false,
      "created_at":"2016-04-07T00:00:00+0200",
      "updated_at":"2016-04-07T10:30:14+0200",
      "expires_at":"2020-04-07T00:00:00+0200",
      "title":"Overnachten bij Bed\u0026Breakfast Mieke",
      "description":"\u003Cp\u003EDe B\u0026amp;B biedt 2 kamers. E\u0026eacute;n tweepersoonskamer met heerlijk bed die van alle gemakken is voorzien,\u0026nbsp; zoals een televisie, f\u0026ouml;hn en een kluisje. De eenpersoonskamer is wat kleiner en heeft dus ook een eenpersoonsbed. Maar ook daarop slaap je als een ware Doornroosje. De kus van de prins is helaas niet in het concept opgenomen, maar het ontbijt is minstens zo verrassend.\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\r\n\u003Cp\u003E\u0026nbsp;\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\r\n\u003Cp\u003EDe kamers zijn voorzien van badjassen en nadat je rustig wakker bent geworden kun je genieten van de ruime inloopdouche. Mieke en Ad zijn ondertussen druk bezig om de tafel gezellig te dekken en een uitgebreid ontbijt klaar te maken. Verse broodjes, thee, koffie, vers fruit, zoet, vleeswaren, jus d\u0026#39;orange, er is voor ieder wat wils! Wanneer je de B\u0026amp;B in de zomer bezoekt is er ook de mogelijkheid om lekker buiten te ontbijten of daarna je kopje koffie te nuttigen in de loungehoek.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\r\n\u003Cp\u003EDe eenpersoonskamer kost \u0026euro;35,- per nacht.\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\r\n\u003Cp\u003EDe tweepersoonskamer kost \u0026euro; 49,50 per nacht voor 2 personen. Deze kamer is ook voor 1 persoon te boeken en kost dan slechts \u0026euro;42,50\u003C\/p\u003E\r\n\r\n\u003Cp\u003EPrijzen zijn inclusief ontbijt,\u0026nbsp; Wifi en toeristenbelasting.\u003C\/p\u003E",
      "coordinates":{  
         "longitude":4.9134973,
         "latitude":51.5874298,
         "type":"Point",
         "coordinates":[  
            4.9134973,
            51.5874298
         ]
      },
      "images":[  
         "57061a86f0bda.png",
         "57061a8dbfcf2.png",
         "57061a9234244.png"
      ],
      "location":{  
         "path":"Nederland-55389c647d387315588b4567|Noord-Brabant-55389c717d387315588b4568|",
         "level":2,
         "id":"55389c717d387315588b4568",
         "slug":"noord-brabant",
         "updated_at":"2016-02-24T17:02:01+0100",
         "title":"Noord-Brabant",
         "coordinates":{  
            "longitude":5.2321687,
            "latitude":51.4826537
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Totally illegible, of course, but what "unnamed array" are you referring to?

Comment: That's not a JSON array, is a JSON object, named with some sort of hex GUID. Including the entire ~30K of JSON is not helpful. Instead include only the portion you care about and cannot access.

Answer (score 0):

JSONObject is a {}, JSONArray is a []. You must create an object passing data to constructor of (in that case) JSONObject. Next you can get data from JSON using get methods or iterating keys with iterator, which you can get from object {}

```
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject(data);
    Iterator<String> iterator = j.keys();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = iterator.next();
        Log.i(key, j.getString(key));
    }
```

if you have data in [] you can do this

```
JSONArray a = new JSONArray(data);
int l = a.length();
for(int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    Log.i(i + "", a.getString(i));
}
```